# print number in order with thread

Tags: java, java-threads

I want create two thread first one even and second one odd and I want have synchronized list to add this number and at last print number in order this is my codes

```
     @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (allNumber) {
            for (int i = 1; i <=number ; i+=2) {
                allNumber.add(i);
                try {
                    allNumber.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

        }
    }
     @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (allNumber){
        for (int i = 0; i <= number; i+=2) {
            allNumber.add(i);
            allNumber.notify();
        }
        }
    }
    public class Main {
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.out.print("Enter Your Number: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();

        List<Integer> sharedList = new ArrayList<>();

        Odd oddThread = new Odd(number, sharedList);
        Even evenThread = new Even(number, sharedList);

        Thread thread = new Thread(oddThread);

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(evenThread);

        thread.start();
        thread1.start();

        System.out.println("List: " + sharedList);

    }
}
```

my output is not in order and its not complete

Comment: I must assume that both `run` methods are in different threads (it would be better to have a [mre] in the question) - after a short look over given code, the second `run()` is not waiting for the first, so it can (and probably will) iterate more than once before the other thread even get a chance to run - but without a [mre], we are not able to see what `Odd`, `Even` or `input` are doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find one way this is my Even class code

```java
public class Even extends Thread {
    private final int input;
    private final List<Integer> allNumbers;

    private List<Integer> evenList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Even(int input, List<Integer> sharedList) {
        this.input = input;
        this.allNumbers = sharedList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (allNumbers) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= input; i += 2) {
                allNumbers.add(i);
                evenList.add(i);
                allNumbers.notify();
                try {
                    if (i < input) {
                        allNumbers.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Even: " + evenList + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I do same for odd class then in main class create a list and pass it to Eeven and Odd class

Answer (score 2):

You wanna the number in order, then you must be sure the threads wait each other.
I suggest you write like this:
**Even**

```
for (int i = 1; i <=number ; i+=2) {
  if(allNumber.size == i){
    synchronized (allNumber) {
      if(allNumber.size == i){
            allNumber.add(i);
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

**Odd**

```
for (int i = 0; i <=number ; i+=2) {
  if(allNumber.size == i){
    synchronized (allNumber) {
       if(allNumber.size == i){
            allNumber.add(i);
       }   
    }
  }
}
```